# How to list docker images in insecure-registry

Tags: docker

I setup a insecure-registry on another server within the same local network. Is there a way to easily list images available on the insecure-registry?

Comment: I'm not sure if the insecure registry is different from the secure registry, so I'm not posting this as an answer: Try https://your-registry.example.com:5000/v2/_catalog

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is another way than directly calling the [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["myfirstimage","mysecondimage"]}

$ curl http://localhost:5000/v2/myfirstimage/tags/list
{"name":"myfirstimage","tags":["latest","toto"]}
```

For a full listing, using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
for repository in $(curl -s http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[]'); do
  curl -s http://localhost:5000/v2/${repository}/tags/list | jq -r '(.name + ":" + .tags[])'
done

myfirstimage:latest
myfirstimage:toto
mysecondimage:latest
```